# LibGDX - trying to display a visible timer in my game

Tags: java, android, timer, bitmap, libgdx

as the title says I'm trying to display a timer in my game that starts from 0 (and ideally, I want it to be on the top left of the screen)

I have the logic for the timer here:

```
public class Timer {
SpriteBatch batch;
private BitmapFont font;
private float deltaTime = 0;
CharSequence str;

public Timer() {
    font = new BitmapFont();
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
}
public void drawTime() {
    deltaTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    str = Float.toString(deltaTime);
    font.draw(batch, str, 0, 0);
}

}
```

I call this timer in my main class (**Game**) in the render() method like so:

```
public void render() {

    player.update();
    platform1.update();
    platform2.update();

    batch.begin();

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(135/255f, 206/255f, 235/255f, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    flag.drawS(batch);
    flag.draw(batch);

    player.draw(batch);

    platform1.draw(batch);
    platform2.draw(batch);

    timer.drawTime();
    batch.end();
}
}
```

I get the error "SpriteBatch begin must be called before draw", so I tried moving the timer.drawTime() method in different places in render() but still no luck.

Anyone know what could be wrong? Any help is highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not create SpriteBatch() inside your Timer object. SpriteBatch should be created once and used by multiple elements to draw themselves. Your Timer draw() method should look more like this:

```
public void drawTime(SpriteBatch batch) {
    deltaTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    str = Float.toString(deltaTime);
    font.draw(batch, str, 0, 0);
}
```

The specific error you are encountering is caused by the fact that you  call `batch.begin();` on a different SpriteBatch object then the one that gets used in `drawTime()`.

Comment: Ah, that does make sense actually (especially when I look at the draw methods of other objects in render()). Made the change but still no timer on the screen

Comment: It might get drawn off the screen or in background color. Also, I would suggest starting with font.draw(batch, "TEST", 0, 0);

Comment: I see, I set its position to (100,00) now and can see it on the bottom left of my screen. I always thought that in android (0,0) was the top left of the screen though, strange. Thanks for the help

Comment: By the way is there any built-in function that allows me to display time in this format: mm:ss

currently it gives it in this format: 6.2323454